# Django + psycopg2 OperationalError could not open certificate file "/root/.postgresql/postgresql.crt": Permission denied

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have a server with ubuntu 22 and a postgres database on digitalocean. I'm deploying a django application there using docker swarm and when I try to access the /admin page **I get this error**:

`connection to server at "xxxx.db.ondigitalocean.com" (xx.xxx.xxx.xx), port 25060 failed: could not open certificate file "/root/.postgresql/postgresql.crt": Permission denied`

I will add that when I created a test script to connect to the database for tests on the server, everything works fine, and I can connect to the database from the local computer. The same project when I run locally connects to the database without any problems

**DB settings**

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": "dbname",
        "USER": "user",
        "PASSWORD": "pass",
        "HOST": "xxxx.db.ondigitalocean.com",
        "PORT": "25060",
    }
}
```

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3.11

ARG GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN

RUN git config --global url."https://${GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com"

WORKDIR /backend

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY entrypoint.sh .
COPY entrypoint-celery.sh .

# ADD /backend /backend
COPY /backend /backend

RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir -p /backend/tmp
RUN chmod -R 777 /backend/tmp

RUN mkdir -p /orders/xmls
RUN chmod -R 777 /orders/xmls
```

Comment: The error message seems self-explanatory.  What did you do to investigate the matter, or why do you think no investigation is needed?

Comment: it seems to me that something is wrong with the dockerfile or with docker-compose.yaml, yesterday I added a test container to docker-compose that uses PYTHON 11 and the same version of psycopg2 and this container connected to the database without any problems

Comment: @KrystianKazimierczak - I am facing a similar issue with flask. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Change version from python3.11 to python 3.10 and it works

Answer (score 4):

Had the same error, found this thread https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1535

I ended up applying this workaround suggested here: https://github.com/nginx/unit/issues/834#issuecomment-1410297997

For your dockerfile just add following

```
ENV PGSSLCERT /tmp/postgresql.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue in a docker container running on Kubernetes. The container was running `gunicorn` with workers. The container was running as root, but the workers threads were running as the `www-data` user. The `$HOME` var was therefore set to `/root`, but the `www-data` user doesn't have access, and so the permission issue. The file does not exist in either user's `$HOME` directory, but the permission failure is handled differently than a missing file.

Switching the container to run as the `www-data` user as well resolved the issue, since the `$HOME` variable now points to a directory the user has access to.

In the Dockerfile, it is possible to [explicitly set the user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user):

```
USER UID[:GID]
```

If you cannot set the user in the Dockerfile (the image is reused in several contexts, that need different users), many tools allow you to specify the user at runtime.

For kubernetes, that means setting the security context

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: <uid>
  runAsGroup: <gid>
```

For a raw docker command, that might mean using the appropriate flag `-u <uid>:<gid>`.

Other tools have similar mechanisms.